# How to get detch data from List which is inside a folder?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS for generating reports, have created the data source and dataset, and I'm able to retrieve the data. However, some items which are inside the folder are not getting displayed in report.

It's not fetching items inside a report.

Dont know how to mention scope here for query. Below is my query:

```xml
      <RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <ListName>Program</ListName>
      <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Title" />
      <FieldRef Name="Requestor" />
      </ViewFields>
      </RSSharePointList>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is, or what you've tried to solve the problem. Could you edit the question and include some more details?